# Runtime Warning: The iteration is not making good progress

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, runtime-error, scipy-optimize

I am getting runtime warnings while using the scipy.fsolve. I have arrays for w, n, k, and lm (float values) and would like to solve for d i.e., return an array of d with a similar dimension. Can anyone please help me out?

```
def func(n, k, d, lm):
    alpha = 4*np.pi*k/lm
    se = ((n-1)**2) / ((n+1)**2) + 0.05*np.ones_like(lm) 
    st = 1.014*np.ones_like(lm) - 4./(n*(n+1)**2)
    r0 = (1-se)/(1-st)
    return 1/(alpha*d*r0+1)
    
d = np.zeros(w.shape)
for i in range(len(w)):
    d[i] = fsolve((lambda d: w[i] - func(n[i], k[i], d, lm[i])), 1.)
```

---

C:\Users\Emran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:175: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the
improvement from the last ten iterations.
warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)

Comment: How are you sure that the equation is solvable for the given _w, n, k, and lm_?

Comment: Yes, it should be solvable.

Comment: With which _w, n, k, and lm_ does the error occur?